# problems with openssl while installing symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm new with Symfony and I just tried to installed it, everything was going well, but then when I installed the Composer using the command:

```
amhg$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I got this message

```
Composer successfully installed to: /Users/amhg/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The OpenSSL library (0.9.8r) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

So I tried to update the version of the OpenSSL library, but I just created a mess, now I don't have any openssl installed

```
amhg$ openssl version -a
-bash: openssl: command not found
```

But the weird thing is, if i go to

```
amhg$ cd /usr/bin
```

and use `ls` I can actually see, these folders:

```
openssOld
openssl
openssOld
```

I already tried different ways to install openssl, but I don't know what do anymore and I'm just making it more complicated

Is it really necessary openssl for using symfony? or composer?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you run `/usr/bin/openssl version -a`? Maybe it's just not installed in your path anymore?

Comment: I got this amhg$ /usr/bin/openssl version -a OUTPUT:
-bash: /usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory

Comment: Whats your operating system?

Comment: my operating system is OSX

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssl
```

it should restore the openssl installation and configuration

And you can install composer by calling install file without https

```
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: Do I need to be in a specific directory? to execute sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssl?

Comment: No, there is no need to be on a specific location

Comment: Ok, I just tried and I got this, sudo: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found. Maybe the command is different for osx, I just looked an alternative option and I read about brew, yesterday I tried to use it but I also got some problems

Comment: is there another alternative?

Comment: You can try this
Type the command: sudo vi /etc/paths
Enter your password if you're asked for it
You will see a list of paths. 
Add /usr/bin
*Save and quit
Restart Terminal from 

How openssl has been installed?

Comment: E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/.paths.swp"

Comment: I made a mistake, the first time I saw a list of paths, but I didn't know how to add them, then I close the terminal, and now I got that message

Comment: You can remove this file
sudo rm /etc/.paths.swp

And edit agin the path file without the warning

Comment: Ok! i tried it, i don't have the error anymore, but then in here sudo vi /etc/paths how should I add /usr/bin... actually is already there, these are the paths I have: /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin, /usr/local/bin and at the end "/etc/paths" 5L, 45C